# Write performance about neo4j when use py2neo

Tags: performance, neo4j, py2neo

I am trying to use neo4j in my application. Now I am facing a few critical
problems in the experiment. The problems statement is divided into such
several parts.

BACKGROUND:

The use case is getting data from internet, the data scale is billion, the
scene is real time, the relationships is just person-to-person with several
properties.

CONFIGURATION:

Machine configuration:

```
  cpu: 24 processors, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz
  memory: 165 203 696 kB
  jdk: java version "1.7.0_67",  Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01),  Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
  Linux version: 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
  OS: CentOS release 6.5
```

Neo4j configuration:

```
  enterprise version: 2.1.5
  jvm heap: default
  objects cache:
  neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=512M
  neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=6G
  neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=5G
  neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1G
  neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1G
```

client configuration:

```
  pyneo, version 1.6.4
```

CODE IN CLIENT:

```
CYPHER_WEIGHT_COMPUTE='r.weight=r.weight+r.weight*EXP((TIMESTAMP()-r.update_time)/(r.half_life*1.0))'

// Initiation, create constraints according the label on id
self.query=neo.CypherQuery(self.graph_db,'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (pn:UID)
ASSERT pn.id IS UNIQUE')
self.query.execute()
self.query=neo.CypherQuery(self.graph_db,'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (pm:GID)
ASSERT pm.id IS UNIQUE')
self.query.execute()

// Cypher clause
MERGE(first:{TYPE1} {{id:'{val1}'}})
MERGE (second:{TYPE2} {{id:'{val2}'}})
MERGE (first)-[r:{RTYPE}]->(second) ON CREATE SET r.weight={weight_set} ON
MATCH SET {weight_compute}
WITH r
SET r.half_life={half_life},
    r.update_time=TIMESTAMP(),
    r.threshold={threshold}
WITH r
WHERE r.weight<r.threshold
DELETE r

self.query=neo.CypherQuery(self.graph_db,self.create_rels.
     format(TYPE1=entity1[0],val1=entity1[1],
            TYPE2=entity2[0],val2=entity2[1],
            RTYPE=rel_type,weight_set=weight_set,

weight_compute=CYPHER_WEIGHT_COMPUTE,half_life=half_life,threshold=threshold))
```

RESULT:

When i use 24 python threads with py2neo writing 59229 nodes, 236048
relationships, 531325 properties. average time expense is about 1316
seconds. The result cann't meet my real time need, it will work well for me
if the time expense decrease to 150 seconds. And the time expense for each
node/relationship will increase when the scale of the data increases

QUESTIONS:

1. Is there any other way of improving the write performance except for
   optimizing the cypher clause and using batch insertion?  I have tried the
   way of configuring different size of jvm heap and objects cache. And i found
   that it effected less on the write performance, i think the reason is maybe
   the small scale of nodes/relationships (from thousands to ten thousands),
   the efficiency may be significant in the big scale of nodes/relationships(
   ten millions, billions)
2. How much nps or rps can neo4j' read and write performance reach according
   your experience in a scale of billion nodes/relationships?
3. I also found that neo4j cann't do sharding automatically, but there is
   one section about cache-based sharding in the document, If i use cache-based
   sharding with HAproxy, how can the relationships between the nodes which has
   been sharding to different machines maintain? That's to say the
   relationships are not broken by the sharding.
4. Can master/slave mode use in both community and enterprise version?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: Are you sure the nodes are getting created with the expected label? AFAIK you can't parameterize the label/reltype. This could affect the label constraint index usage.

Comment: I think for your massive data. I'd not go with cypher but with a server extension that has a dedicated endpoint to consume large chunks of your data and then batches the inserts accordingly, with the Neo4j Java API.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have already done like this. And i think i have addressed the performance problem, but the sharding problem is now critical. We cann't use the cache-based sharding due to the massive data, the connected and mutable nature of graphs. I think i should give up graph database.

Answer (score 5):

1. Must you do these as different requests? I recommend you use the transactional cypher endpoint: http://nigelsmall.com/py2neo/1.6/cypher/#id2
2. Depends on the query and API used. And your method of counting reads and writes. With the transactional http API, I've managed to get 30k cypher create statements per second with two nodes and a rel. Merge is a fair bit slower, and you need to make sure you're using the constraint index.
3. The idea is to keep a subset of the data cached by allowing a subset of users (or subset you can define) to query on particular cluster nodes. If the relationship a query needs to follow isn't cached, it will end up reading from disk. All data must be on the disks of all members of the cluster.
4. I'm not certain, but I'm pretty sure all the clustering features come with enterprise.

Comment: Just realized I answered a slightly different #2. 1B nodes/rels should be fine, you're going to want a lot of ram.

Comment: Hi Wes, The third answer i also have some doubt about it. Let's say, if there is one path (a)-(b)-[n..]-(q), where n>500. The nodes in the path have been sharding to different machines'cache, then how can you guarantee the relationship between the nodes not broken ? Thanks

Comment: The key thing I think you're missing in this sharded cache concept is that all the data must be on all of the machines. The cache holds a subset and must read from disk in the case of a cache miss.

Comment: Okay, I think I have known about the meaning of cache sharding. But it cann't address the problem yet when the data scale is too big that it cann't be stored in a few machines. Maybe this problem is actually a NP-hard problem due to the connected and mutable nature of graphs